# Cannot get head of sparkR data frame

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I use sparkR to run some sql query to get sparkR data frame like the following

```
data = sql(sql_query)
```

And I can get the dimension of data by using `dim(data)`

However, when I want to take a look at the data by using `head(data)` it will fail and give me an error `java.lang
.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.TimestampWritable cannot be
cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable`

I tried the sql query in Hive and it doesn't have any problem. The weird thing here is I can get the dimension but cannot get the head.

Any idea?

Comment: There is really not enough information here. Please [edit] your question and provide [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185/8371915)

Answer (score 0):

Try: `View(head(data, 20))`...also, it would be helpful if you could give a little bit more detail on your question.